# Adding an id to the <circle> tag is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, graphics, svg, raphael

I'm trying to add an id attribute to the `<circle>` tag using jQuery's `.attr()`:

```
r.circle(x, y, 6).attr({fill: "#ff0000", stroke: "none", id: "cir1"}),
```

The problem is that it adds the `fill` and `stroke` attributes but not `id`. I know because I look at the Google Chrome DEV and it's not showing the `id`!

Comment: What happens if you try to add the `id` alone, without the `fill` or the `stroke`?

Comment: Nothing...It still doesn't work.
I'm using the Raphael Framework

Comment: Oops! I didn't read the `svg` tag. Silly me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me.

Proof: open [this test page](http://phrogz.net/svg/transparent_svg.xhtml) and open your developer console. You will see `"yay  1  circle"` in the output, which is the result of this JavaScript code:

```
var head = $('circle:eq(1)');
head.attr({id:'yay'});
console.log(
  head[0].id,
  $('#yay').length,
  document.getElementById('yay').tagName
);
```

From this you can see that the `id` attribute is both a) being set on the DOM element, and b) working as a means for accessing the element through either jQuery or DOM methods.

Can you provide a working test case, perhaps using Raphael, showing this failing?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, you can't add an `id` using `attr`.  See here:

http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#attr

If you need the `id` as a hook, perhaps you could set a `title`, which is allowed.

---

An aside:

It's hard to tell from the docs if this is allowed, but maybe you can add the `id` as a custom `attr` by placing it in quotes?

```
"id" : "cir1"
```

Comment: What do you mean but use title? How?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you are using the `id` for... but if you want to use it to reference the circle, perhaps you could use the `title` attribute instead.

Comment: Reference to it like this: `$('circle[title="cir1"]')` after you set a title

Comment: My thoughts exactly @Nathan.  Thanks for adding.

Comment: So like this:  r.circle(x, y, 6).attr({fill: "#ff0000", stroke: "none", title: "cir1"}),

Comment: and then:
$('circle[title="cir1"]').mousemove(function(){
t=false;
});

Comment: @Shawn31313 Seems right to me also. Try it and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can't set the id thru attr.

Just get the node reference and set it directly.

```
r.circle(...).node.id = 'cir1';
```

Answer (score -2):

In some instances you do not need an ID.

You can use the keyword `this`.